# open a new window of view when call controller from Jquery Ajax post call

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, jquery

I'm using ASP.Net MVC2. I'm trying to open a new window of view when call controller from Jquery Ajax post call.
here is my code..
in ascx page..

```
$('#DeleteButton').click(function () {

            var isLineChecked = $(':checkbox:checked', '#providerSearchResultsTable').length;

            if (isLineChecked == 0) {
                alert("Please select at least one row ");
                return false;
            }

            else {

                var params = {
                    Id: gaiSelected.join(',')

                };

                alert(params);
                $.ajax({

                    type: "Post",
                    url: "SelectProviderAndContact",
                    data: params,
                    success: function (html) {
                        **//$('#SelectProviderAndContact').html(html);**
    }
                });

            }
 });
```

here is my controller Action method

```
[SessionFilter]
        public ActionResult SelectProviderAndContact(string Id)
        {
            try
            {
                List<ProviderBaseInfo> providerList = null;
                string[] internalProviderIDs = Id.Split(",".ToCharArray());
                //string[] billingProviderNames = billingProvider.Split(",".ToCharArray());

                IStateBag stateBag = _commonModel.GetStateBag();
                //stateBag.SetValue("InternalProviderId", Id);
                List<Guid> internalProviderIds = new List<Guid>();
                foreach (var a in internalProviderIDs)
                {
                    internalProviderIds.Add(new Guid(a));
                }

                List<Contacts> providerContactList = _providerModel.GetProviderContactlist(internalProviderIds);

                if (providerContactList.Count <= 0)
                {
                     //IStateBag stateBag = GetStateBag();
                    List<ProviderBaseInfo> providers = (List<ProviderBaseInfo>)stateBag.GetValue(ProviderListCache);

                if (providers == null)
                {
                    providerList = _providerModel.GetProviderCompleteList(null, null, null, null, Id).ToList();

                }
                else
                {
                    providerList = providers.Where(x => internalProviderIds.Contains(x.InternalProviderId)).ToList();
                }

                providerContactList = _providerModel.GetContactlistbyInsertingProviders(providerList);
                }

                ViewData["ProviderNotFound"] = false;

               // ViewData["ProviderName"] = new SelectList(billingProvider.Select(x => new { value = x, text = x }), "value", "text");
                var Provider = new[] { 
                new { ProviderId = "A", Providername = "A" }
                //new DataContracts.RegionKeyValues { RegionId = "B", RegionValue = "B" }, 
                //new DataContracts.RegionKeyValues { RegionId = "D", RegionValue = "D" } 
            };
                ViewData["ProviderName"] = new SelectList(Provider, "ProviderId", "Providername");

                **return View("SelectProviderAndContact",providerContactList);**



            }
            catch (FaultException<MedicareFault> ex)
            {
                if (ex.Code.Name == typeof(ArgumentException).Name)
                {
                    ViewData["ProviderNotFound"] = true;
                    ViewData["Error"] = ex.Reason;
                    return View((object)null);
                }
                else
                {
                    ViewData["Error"] = Errors.Common.UnknownError;
                    return View((object)null);
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                ViewData["Error"] = Errors.Common.UnknownError;
                return View((object)null);
            }
        }
```

and I have created `SelectProviderAndContact.aspx` in view.

Please any one help me to open another window with `SelectProviderAndContact.aspx`
from ajax post call.

Answer (score 0):

Your jquery will have to do almost all the work in opening a window. Using the `window.open()` method in your javascript you can make your controller send back a specific argument that causes it to open a new window with a certain URL (i.e. `TheSmallPopupPageThatViewsResults.aspx?resultId=12345` or something).

Your controller would just decide whether or not to tell the view to open the new window and the view would then open it if it is told to.

With your specific implementation, you may have to create a model or something that stores results in the database so that the controller can save the result and the action and view that are for the popup page can then access that result. Another way of doing it would be to have the arguments that the popup page is called with determine what is viewed on the page. This would eliminate the need for another model, but your urls could get really long really fast if you have a lot of data and I believe that there is generally a limit to how long those urls can be.

I would recommend using JSON or XML to return the data to the javascript so that you can extend the returned object as much as needed. The way I have done it in the past is made several XML tags like `<alert>`, `<refresh>`, `<redirect>`, `<somePageSpecificAction>`, etc that I have jquery parse using `$(theEnclosingTag).each( function () { //...parse here })`.

I use mainly MVC3 so I don't know if this is supported in MVC2, but changing ActionResult to JsonResult for the return type and using `return this.Json(new { put = "data here" });` for your return statements makes it really easy to use json.

Also, It may be beneficial to use a different action method to process ajax requests. You would then have one action that displays the page, another action to process ajax requests from that page (it could be decorated with [HttpPost] or something), and another method for your popup page view. That would also keep your code short and easier to read. Having long controller methods can get really confusing later down the line when you try to find the location of a specific bug.

EDIT: A specific example: Assuming MVC3 (since that is what I use...I think you can find other ways of doing this...you could use an xml serializer and just output xml) you have your page (Action #1) that displays with all your buttons and stuff (this is where you javascript containing the $("#DeleteButton") and such goes as well). Your javascript makes its AJAX call to another action (SelectContactAJAX or something...this is action #2) with a few arguments which has a return type of JsonResult. Your javascript gets the response back from that ajax-specific action and the response tells it "open a window with the URL /SelectContactForm?choiceId=12345" (or something). The choiceId is a reference that would be used in the background for the SelectContactForm action (yet another separate action...action #3) to know what to display. Your ajax would then call window.open("/SelectContactForm?choiceId=12345") and when the window opens, it calls action #3 which looks up the reference for what it should be displaying and then shows that to the user.

As for getting feedback on what the user entered in the new window and having the original page react, there are various ways in javascript to listen for window closings and such, but I haven't ever had to use this in one of my applications and it is a bit out of the scope of this question.

Comment: thanks much your explanation. can you give me any example to achieve above condition so that it would be great help

Comment: I added a more specific example above. I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

use colorbox jquery plugin

http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox

write code in .aspx page to call .ascx page

```
  parent.$.fn.colorbox({ href: '/IGTR/SaveIGTRPreference/' + id + '?t=' + Math.random(), height: "400", width: "800", overlayClose: false, escKey: false
        });
```

Here SaveIGTRPreference is .ascx page